# Python - Issues with selenium button click using XPath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following code to click a button on a page but the XPath keeps changing so the code keeps breaking:

`mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/form[2]/span/span/input").click()`

Is there a better way I should be doing this? Here is the code for the button I am trying to click:

`<input class="a-button-input" type="submit" title="Button 2" name="submit.button2-click.x" value="Button 2 Click"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is really intelligent. You could do a much more simple search for that:

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='submit.button2-click.x']")
```

which tells: search all `input` elements whose `name` equals to `'submit.button2-click.x'` which will be the element of your choice.

Don't forget to try Firefix [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) add-on before going to code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use findelement(by.name(" submit.button2-click.x")).click() or use find element(by.cssSelector("selector ")).click()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This also works `mydriver.find_element_by_name("submit.button2-click.x").click()`